# Saving multiple videos at the same time with opencv

Tags: opencv

For my project I have multiple cameras and I need to save the video feed to multiple output files at the same time. Here's my code:

```
import cv2

def one_cam_is_open(list_of_cams):
    for cam in list_of_cams:
        if cam.isOpened():
            return True
    return False

cam_list = []
 # Capture video from camera
for i in range(0, 2):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
    if cap!=-1:
        cam_list.append(cv2.VideoCapture(i))
# the width and height of all cameras will be 1900x1080
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) + 0.5)
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) + 0.5)
dim = (1900, 1080)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v') # Be sure to use the lower case

video_writers = {}
for i, cam in enumerate(cam_list):
    video_writers[cam] = cv2.VideoWriter("output_" + str(i) + ".mp4", fourcc, 20.0, dim)

while one_cam_is_open(cam_list):
    for (cam, out) in video_writers:#TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable cv2.VideoCapture object
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)

            # write the flipped frame
            out.write(frame)

            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
                break
        else:
            break

# Release everything if job is finished
for (cam, out) in video_writers:
    out.release()
    cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As noted in the code, I get the error `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable cv2.VideoCapture object` when I try to unpack the references to the VideoWriter obejects for each camera.

Is there a way to write to multiple video files using VideoWriter?

Comment: video_writers[i] has only an object not a tuple so it is not possible to unpack. Maybe you wanted to do something like `video_writers[i] = (cam, cv2.VideoWriter(........))` in the for loop before the while, here is where the error occurs BTW, you pas cam and not i as an index. Also you do `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)` and then you do `cam_list.append(cv2.VideoCapture(i))` but in this last line probably it fails to open the camera again, because it is in use.... you should pass cap to the append

Comment: Since `video_writers` is a dictionary and you seem to want both key and value, perhaps `for (cam, out) in video_writers.iteritems():` ?